# How to unhinge 2 objects?

Tags: objects

I created a Thorus after a Plane.
[image]
Now somehow if i move the Thorus, the plane moves with it. I just guess it's because the Thorus shares the Plane's cursor/pivot point/3d cursor.

Why did this happen and how can i 'unhinge/unmerge' the objects?
It seems to me that the Thorus parented itself to the Plane. But that doesn't show in the Outliner Panel?

I would have made a small demo video demonstrating this, but i don't know how. I hope the screenshot snippet will suffice!

Thanks for reading!

Comment: It must be because you've enabled the Proportional Editing (blue sphere icon on the top)

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That was it!:-)